# sending data from R to postgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a data frame
 SomeData
1 2015-06-05
2   16:00:00
3         19
4         40
5        985
6         69
7         22

I want to send this data into my postgreSQL table. i have done all the pre-requisite stuff. The data base is connected properly. I can easily send data through dbSendQuery.
but this dataset is an object data
the command for dbSendQuery(con,"Insert into data values('A','b','C')")
Here A , b, c refers to data[1], data[2], data[3]
i want the values to be exported but it sends them as 
data[1] data[2] data[3]
rather than
1 2 3

Answer (score 3):

Package RPostgreSQL has **dbWriteTable** which enables you to store data in command like this:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "tableName", df, append=TRUE, row.names=0)
```

Just keep in mind that column names of your data frame (df) have to be same as fields in the db table.